# Bind sweet alert to dynamically added elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sweetalert2

Sweet alert is not triggered on elements i inject in DOM.

I am using sweet alert 2 gem (https://github.com/nicolasblanco/sweet-alert2-rails) in my rails 5 application, and it works great until I add elements with js response. I understand that I have to bind sweet alert event listeners by invoking them after adding elements, but I don't know how.

Somewhere the gem is initializing sweet alert and binding events on my HTML elements with `data-confirm` attribute turning them into `data-sweet-alert-confirm`. I guess I'll have to call that init function after injecting new elements.

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

In view file:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.js"></script>

<div id="append_div" style="margin:20px;"></div>

<button id="add_element">Add Element</button>
```

In js code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('click', '#add_element', function(){                    
            $(document).find('#append_div').append( 
                '<button class="_appended_btn" style="margin:10px;">Open sweet alert</button>' 
            );
        });


        $(document).on('click', '._appended_btn', function(){
            Swal.fire({     
               type: 'success',
               title: 'Your work has been done',
               showConfirmButton: false,
               timer: 1500
            })
        });

    });
</script>
```